# Java виртуальная память

Tags: java

Как задать максимальное количество используемой памяти для java ?
Держу сервер MineCraft - максимально можно задать в поддержку для сервера 1гб виртуалки, каким способом можно задать большее количество выделяемой памяти ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать 2 гига хипа/кучи:

> java -xmx2g <myClass>

Вообще почитайте документацию к Java. Запустите

> java -X